# How can I replace special characters in a String globally via a JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, replace, frontend

I'm new to development, such as JavaScript, and I am still learning.
Currently, I'm running a Shopware6 shop which is close to going live.
At the moment, I'm facing a problem in which I want to replace certain parts of String globally.
The Shop can be found under https://bt-baushop.de
There are 4 major occurrences in which I want to replace a "+" from article titles:

1. Product search (defined by the class .search-suggest-product-name)
2. Product listings (defined by the class .product-name)
3. On Product pages, at the Main product title (.defined by the class .product-name)
4. On Product pages at the product information title (defined by the class .product-detail-description-title)

I've tried to use the following function for issue nr 4.:

```
const innerText = document.querySelector('.product-detail-description-title').innerText 
document.querySelector('.product-detail-description-title').innerText = innerText.replace('+', '')
```

This did work, but now I need to resolve the other issues. Therefore, I thought it might be a good idea to replace the "+" globally since I can not run the same script twice neither does this work for the product listing since only the 1st occurrence of + is replaced. Also, I'm aware that this possible global solution might kill any occurrences elsewhere in the system, which would be fine.

Btw, the proper way to fix this is simply to rename the field in my ERP-System which are mapped to these classes. However, this is not an option at the moment since I need these article namings for other internal processes. That's why I thought a frontend replacement via JavaScript could be at least a temporary solution.

Hopefully the community can help :)

Comment: No, a frontend replace-all will break more things than to fix them. Do the proper solution of mapping the values in your ERP system, or the shop connector.

Comment: Frontend logic should never ever be responsible for fixing either broken business logic or inaccurately  maintained business data.

Comment: It looks like you're partially sending server side rendered HTML-Fragment strings around (I tried the product search at this shop-site). What does hold one back from adapting the very backend process/es which is/are responsible for the HTML-templating to be adapted to what the FE is expected to do?

Comment: Hallo together, 
I've implemented the following temporary JavaScript: const productNames = document.querySelectorAll('.product-name, .product-detail-name, .product-detail-description-title, .product-list-title, .search-suggest-product-name, .search-suggest-product js-result')

productNames.forEach(function(element) {
   const innerText = element.innerText
   element.innerText = innerText.replace("+", '')
})

Comment: However, I will do proper mappings in My ERP-System with a fallback option which takes the previously mapped field in case the new one is not yet in use, since it takes some time to maintain 600 articles.
Thx, for your answers :)

Answer (score 4):

I pick up the comment of [bergi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1048572/bergi)

> frontend replace-all will break more things than to fix them. Do the proper solution of mapping the values in your ERP system, or the shop connector

This is a solution though in PHP.

To actually do that you can either influence the connector software or you can step in at writing the product. Changing the connector is something we can't comment on as we do not know the software. In Shopware you can listen to the [`product.written` event](https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/plugins/framework/data-handling/using-database-events#product.written). This can be used to react on the moment a product is written via API. Within the event you have the used payload of the update. If there is the name in the payload you can start building your replacement logic and write the product again. This will trigger product.written again, but this time it is fixed and therefore you do not trigger the update again.

The implementation could look like this

```
public function productWritten(EntityWrittenEvent $event): void
{
    $updates = [];

    foreach ($event->getPayloads() as $payload) {
        if (str_contains($payload['name'], '+')) {
            $updates[] = [
                'id' => $payload['id'],
                'name' => str_replace('+', ' ', $payload['name']),
            ];
        }
    }

    if ($updates !== []) {
        $this->productRepository->update($updates, $event->getContext());
    }
}
```

When you look for a solution in JS you could build a Shopware app using the [Admin API](https://shopware.stoplight.io/docs/admin-api/) remotely.